# How to align a node's text RIGHT, i.e. at the end of the line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nodes

I'm drawing a diagram with nodes and I have to have the inner text of one node at the END of the line, i.e. at the right side, not left, not centered. Unfortunately I didn't find a way nor information in the web.

That's how my picture now looks like:
[image]

As you can see the text in the node "Client" (right side) is covered by the "Anwendungsprogramm"-node. How can I shove the text on the right side of the node?

The code: 
(It's a large document, that's why I use this many packages. For I'm not sure which packages do influence my graphics, I'll take all.)

```
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}      
\begin{tikzpicture}     

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=25mm, text width=40mm,
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=black!10]                      
           (server)     {Server};

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=20mm, text width=25mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, text centered, 
           right=20mm of server]    
           (webservice) {Webservice};              

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=20mm, text width=20mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=white!100, text centered, 
           right=-25mm of server]   
           (server-p)   {Anwen-\\ dungs-\\ programm};              

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=25mm, text width=40mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=black!10, text centered, 
           right=20mm of webservice]    
           (client) {Client};          

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=20mm, text width=20mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=white!100, text centered, 
           left=-25mm of client]    
           (client-p)   {Anwen-\\ dungs-\\ programm};

    \draw [<->, very thick] (webservice) to (server-p);
    \draw [<->, very thick] (webservice) to (client-p);

\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
\label{fig-funktionaleebenen}   
\end{center}    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — How did you do it with the `Server` node?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you delete `text centered` as one of the `\node` options for client and then do as @GonzaloMedina suggested: add `align=right`, this will right align the content of the node.[image]

Here is a minimimal corrected code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{calc,multirow,tikz,array,setspace,geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}     

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=25mm, text width=40mm,
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=black!10]                      
           (server)     {Server};

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=20mm, text width=25mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, text centered, 
           right=20mm of server]    
           (webservice) {Webservice};              

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=20mm, text width=20mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=white!100, text centered, 
           right=-25mm of server]   
           (server-p)   {Anwen-\\ dungs-\\ programm};              

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=25mm, text width=40mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=black!10, align = right, 
           right=20mm of webservice]    
           (client) {Client};          

    \node [rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, minimum size=20mm, text width=20mm, 
            anchor=base, very thick, draw=black!50, fill=white!100, text centered, 
           left=-25mm of client]    
           (client-p)   {Anwen-\\ dungs-\\ programm};

    \draw [<->, very thick] (webservice) to (server-p);
    \draw [<->, very thick] (webservice) to (client-p);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I noticed this just now. Tried the alignment on wrong node first. @_@